# How to distribute data into matrix format in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

Because of the structual nature of dataset, I plan to use VBA in Excel 2010 to process the dataset. The main characteristics of the dataset include three main columns as illustrated:

```
FromID, ToID, Amount
10,     10,   50
10,     11,   67
10,     12,   56
11,     10,   60
11,     11,   80
12,     10,   17
12,     11,   57
```

Of course this is the simplified version of the data and the origional data is much complicated than this. The FromID include the point who sends the data and ToID is the poin who receives the data. The amount indicate the size of the data. What I want is, based on the FromID and ToID, to generate a n*n matrix to store the dateset in matrix format in excel,

What i want, the matrix should be as follows:

```
                10  11   12  
10 ---          50  67   56
11 ---          60  80   17
12 ---          ...
```

I now have such type of data in columns but I am a noob in VBA and i dont have too much experience. I am wondering is that possible to give me some suggestions about the logics (detailed?) and if possible, could you provide some code snippets with some explanations about how to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Will there be more than one row like  **10, 11, something**  ??

Answer (score 1):

You may not need any **VBA** coding.  Excel has a facility called a **Pivot Table** to create two dimensional tables of this type.  See:

[Introduction](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Pivots/pivottables.htm)